# Enforcing child records

Tags: validation

I wonder if anyone had come across this problem before and come up with a neat solution.

Imagine you have a parent object and a child object. In this scenario you should always have at least one child record but potentially many. How do you enforce the creation of the first child?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I knew this sounded familiar!

Comment: Thank you @AdrianLarson. that's exactly the problem I'm having. Sorry my searching skills didn't pull it up. Ta!

Comment: @JoeHarrison You should be able to mark that you agree with the duplicate vote and it will close it for you. Welcome to SFSE!

Answer (score 2):

First, create a roll-up summary field that sums children. Then, create a validation rule like this:

```
NOT(ISNEW()) && Num_Children__c = 0
```

Users will be allowed to create new records, but cannot edit them until at least one child is added.

Comment: I prefer `Count` over `Num` in my API Names.